# Are social justice perspectives more often agent-centered or patient-centered deontology?

Tags: ethics, deontology

According to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on [deontology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/), there are two main types of deontology - agent-centered and patient-centered. Which kind are social justice views of philosophy more likely to be?

Comment: what is a `social justice view of philosophy`?

Comment: Unquestionably patient-centered.

Comment: SJWs aren't really about having a coherent philosophical approach, and they very wildly.